# Get the button type in order to use the ref attribute on a blazor button

Tags: razor, blazor-server-side

Built a blazor server app in VS 2022, .net 6.0.

I have a razor page with a button:

`<button @ref="btnMe" class="btn btn-primary">ME</button>`

and I am trying to do something very simple: access that button directly in the @code block. I only need to do declare the matching variable.
The question is, what type do I use for the variable? I have not been able to find that out. In other words, please tell me what I should use for the ????

```
@code{
  ...
  private ???? btnMe;  ...
}
```

Also tell me how/where you found out the answer. Hovering over the control gave no info, and I could not find any documentation on the blazor `<button>` element.

Comment: The type is ELementReference, but you can't do much with it - setting Focus is quite useful. [blazor-university.com](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/passing-html-element-references/)

Comment: What do you want to do with your button, exactly?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it.  `@ref` does in fact show you what it is if you hover it: an `object`

Comment: @BennyBoy I want to be able to reference all controls in code, so as to be able to manipulate them in a consistent fashion.

Comment: @Magoo, yes thank you. It is an element reference and has Focus extension methods. I was expecting a more specific type, for example like InputText, complete with more properties/methods as InputText has. However, declaring ```private ElementReference btnMe;``` in the code does not help. If I were to type btnMe followed by a dot. intellisense shows me nothing.

Comment: Your answer is not an answer.  In what way do you want to "manipulate them in a consistent fashion?"  How a button works is you click it, and that triggers an event, which you handle.  What more do you want from it?

Comment: @BennyBoy in my sentence above, 'them' refers to 'all controls'. I don't know how many textboxes, buttons, dropdowns,, etc.. I will have on each razor page, but as I stated I want to be able to manipulate them in a consistent fashion. That is to have access to all properties, events, attributes, etc... in the code for any control that I have put in the markup. In the earlier .NET Web forms world, creating a markup element created the ref control in code automatically and gave you that access and consistency. I want to accomplish the same in Blazor, using element <button> as an example.

Comment: Controls are aspx things, and you will have to let them go.  You aren't going to directly modify properties (box size, color, etc.) in Blazor like you would with web forms.  So unless you can suggest a use case, i.e. a particular "manipulation" you might do, in which case I'd be happy to show you how to do it, there's really not much I can tell you except that Blazor is not Web Forms.